# pdf2image conversion of multi page PDFs to images returns the last page on all images

Tags: python, pdf2image

So when I use the `pdf2image` python import, and pass a multi page PDF into the `convert_from_bytes()`- or `convert_from_path()` method, the output array does contain multiple images - but all images are of the last PDF page (whereas I would've expected that each image represented one of the PDF pages).

The output looks something like this:

[image: pdf2image conversion bug]

Any idea on why this would occur? I can't find any solution to this online. I've found some vague suggestion that the `use_cropbox` argument might be used, but modifying it has no effect.

```
def convert(opened_file)
    # Read PDF and convert pages to PPM image objects
    try:
        _ppm_pages = self.pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(
            opened_file.read(),
            grayscale = True
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[CreateJPEG] Could not convert PDF pages to JPEG image due to error: \n    '{e}'")
        return

    # Do stuff with _ppm_pages
    for img in _ppm_pages:
        img.show() # ...all images in that list are of the last page
```

Sometimes the output is an empty 1x1 image, instead, which I also haven't found a reason for. So if you have any idea what that is about, please do let me know!

Thanks in advance,
Simon

EDIT: Added code.

EDIT: So, when I try this in a random notebook, it actually works fine.

I've removed a few detours I used in my original code, and now it works. Still not sure what the underlying reason was though...

All the same, thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: can you post full code ?

Comment: @balu, added code!

Comment: Has anyone found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this right now....

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

imgSet = convert_from_path(pathToPDF, 500)
```

That gives me a list of images within imgSet

Comment: Right, I'm getting a set as well, but all images in that set are the same image - the last PDF page. If you look at all images in your imgSet, does each image represent a distinct page, or are they all images of the last page in the set?

Comment: They are unique pages... (now off to quadruple check just to be sure to be sure - but 99.9999% sure they were different)

Comment: Should be... When I try to do the same thing in a random notebook, it seems to work just fine. Very confused.

Comment: Yeah, confirm as definitely different. Bit of a puzzle all right. I wonder is pdf2image using some underlying pdf property that is messed up? But strange that it then gives you the right number of pages, just doesn't iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to do something like this as described in the unit tests of the package.

```py
        with open("./tests/test.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:
            images_from_bytes = convert_from_bytes(pdf_file.read(), fmt="jpg")
            self.assertTrue(images_from_bytes[0].format == "JPEG")
```

Comment: Right, just tried that at your suggestion.

Unfortunately, it had no impact on the images output. All images are still of the last PDF page